# Center align bootstrap nav buttons

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap, navbar

I have my nav buttons and I would like to center align them in such a way that when shrinking the browser, the buttons should just shrink and not move onto a new line. I have tried various things but nothing worked. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

I have provided the jsfiddle below.

```
.navbar .navbar-nav {
    display: inline-block;
    float: none;
}
```

[JsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/bdd9U/1273/)

Comment: I don't really understand what you mean by "buttons should just shrink and not move onto a new line". Care to explain/add some demo of what the outcome should be?

Comment: you might be running up against bootstrap's built-in media queries. there are a couple of weird breakpoints. one where "View all our products" jumps over navigation, another where "Pet Insurance" drops a line, and the last one where it turns into a mobile view.

Comment: yeah exactly. I can either reduce the font size and padding in those two scenarios to make it work at 1200px and 1000px widths or something else.

Comment: if you want your nav buttons not wrap below, you need to adjust its width and font size accordingly using media query, but you have many buttons so i dont think it's possible to remain it centered and not wrapping down below. however you can put `whitespace:nowrap` to its parent so it will not move downward when the screen size shrinks.

Answer (score 0):

I think this is what you're looking for... You may need to switch the .navbar's around, I'm not sure what order you want them in.

```
.navbar .navbar-nav {
display: inline-block;
float: none;
}

.navbar {
width: 235px;
padding-left:30px
}

.navbar-nav {
float: center; 
width: 235px; 
margin: 0; 
padding: 0;
}
```